# ¿Como puedo destruir un summernote?

Tags: javascript, modal

Tengo un modal en donde lanzo un Summernote, sin embargo quiero que al salir del modal el Summernote se destruya ya que puede pasar lo siguiente:

[image]

Y si le quito el contenido con **$("#descripcionA").code("");** no quita el texto, solo se quita si recargo la pagina.

Comment: Has probado con `$("#descripcionA").summernote('destroy');` al cerrar tu modal?

Comment: Esta perfecto @Edu3D muchas gracias

Comment: @Edu3D como eso parece ser la solucion, puedes redactar una respuesta siguiendo [answer] para que Bernardo te la acepte. Un saludo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes añadir en lugar de:

```
 $("#descripcionA").code("");
```

Esto:

```
$("#descripcionA").summernote('destroy');
```

Al cerrar tu modal.